# How to use keyboard arrows for input in a VCL forms application with TButtons

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

I have a VCL forms application where I'm intercepting keys pressed in the OnKeyPress and OnKeyDown handlers. This works fine for regular characters and keys like VK_ESC for example.

However, when trying to catch the arrow keys (VK_UP and VK_DOWN), it does not work as they seem only to be changing the focus of the controls on the main form, and are not triggering the main forms OnKeyDown handler.

How does one catch/process those key presses?

Update:
Trying the following, based on answer below, but still no success.

```
void __fastcall TMain::WndProc(TMessage& Message)
{
  switch (Message.Msg)
  {
    case WM_GETDLGCODE:
        Log(lInfo) << "Got WM_GETDLGCODE";
    break;
    case CM_WANTSPECIALKEY:
        Log(lInfo) << "Got WM_WANTSPECIALKEY";
    break;
```

None of the above cases are triggered by using the up/down arrows in my application.

I have made the following observation. If creating an empty vcl form, the above cases **are** triggered, CM_WANSPECIALKEY is triggered first, followed by WM_GETDLGCODE.

However, as soon as a TButton is placed on the form, the cases are not triggered anymore.

I'm using C++ Builder XE3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arrow keys are reserved by Windows for navigation purposes.  If a window wants to handle arrow key messages, it must respond to the [`WM_GETDLGCODE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645425.aspx) message and include the `DLGC_WANTARROWS` (or `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`) flag in its return value.

Most VCL UI components (including `TForm`) return 0 for `WM_GETDLGCODE`.  Only a handful of standard VCL components respond with `DLGC_WANTARROWS` (or `DLGC_WANTALLKEYS`):

`TColorGrid`, `TToolBar`, `TCustomGrid`, `TMediaPlayer`, `TCustomRibbon`, `TRibbonSpinButton`, `TSpinButton`, `TTabbedNotebook`, `TCustomCombo`, and `TTabSet`

In your `TForm` class, override its virtual `WndProc()` method, or declare a `message` handler, to handle `WM_GETDLGCODE`, then you can return whatever flag(s) you need.

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
        Message.Result |= DLGC_WANTARROWS;
}
```

---

**Update**: If `WM_GETDLGCODE` doesn't work, try responding to the `CM_WANTSPECIALKEY` message instead:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == CM_WANTSPECIALKEY)
    {
        switch (reinterpret_cast<TCMWantSpecialKey&>(Message).CharCode)
        {
            case VK_LEFT:
            case VK_RIGHT:
            case VK_UP:
            case VK_DOWN:
                Message.Result = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**: you are trying to process key events in the Form itself, which will only work when:

- the Form window itself has input focus.
- a child VCL window receives key messages, and the Form's `KeyPreview` property is true.

When a windowed child control, like a button, has the input focus, key messages go to that window, not to the Form window.  In order for the `KeyPreview` property to work for arrow keys, the focused child must respond to the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message asking the OS to send arrow key messages.  Only then can the child forward the messages to the Form for processing.

A button doesn't ask for arrow key messages by default, so you would have to subclass the button to handle the `WM_GETDLGCODE` message manually, eg:

```
class TMain : public TForm
{
__published:
    TButton *Button1;
    void __fastcall FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, Word &Key, TShiftState Shift);
    void __fastcall FormKeyPress(TObject *Sender, Char &Key);
private:
    TWndMethod PrevBtnWndProc;
    void __fastcall BtnWndProc(TMessage &Message);
public:
    __fastcall TMain(TComponent *Owner);
};

__fastcall TMain::TMain(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    PrevBtnWndProc = Button1->WindowProc;
    Button1->WindowProc = &BtnWndProc;
}

void __fastcall TMain::BtnWndProc(TMessage &Message
{
    PrevBtnWndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
        Message.Result |= DLGC_WANTARROWS;
}

void __fastcall TMain::FormKeyDown(TObject *Sender, Word &Key, TShiftState Shift)
{
    // works now!
}

void __fastcall TForm7::FormKeyPress(TObject *Sender, Char &Key)
{
    // works now!
}
```

That is fine if you have only a few controls to subclass, but if you have a lot of controls, an alternative solution would be to have your Form class handle the `CM_DIALOGKEY` message instead:

```
void __fastcall TMyForm::WndProc(TMessage &Message)
{
    TForm::WndProc(Message);
    if (Message.Msg == CM_DIALOGKEY)
    {
        switch (reinterpret_cast<TCMDialogKey&>(Message).CharCode)
        {
            case VK_LEFT:
            case VK_RIGHT:
            case VK_UP:
            case VK_DOWN:
                // process key as needed...
                // set Message.Result to suppress the message further...
                Message.Result = 1;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

You should read the following article on EDN, it has a good explanation of how the VCL processes key messages, and how the VCL implements various hooks you can use to intercept key messages:

[A Key’s Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447)

Comment: I'm trying your suggestion of overriding WndProc(). 

I have in my Main Forms WndProc the following: 

   void __fastcall TMain::WndProc(TMessage& Message)
   {
     if(Message.Msg == WM_GETDLGCODE)
     {
     Log(lInfo) << "Got WM_GETDLGCODE";
        //Message.Result = DLGC_WANTARROWS;
    .....
But even though I'm clicking on an arrow key, I never trap the message. Also, where, how  does one 'switch' to wanting arrows? Sorry for the confusion and not sure how to add formatted code to a comment..

Comment: This approach seem not to work properly, see my update above. As soon a TButton is put on the main form, and thereby unfocusing it, no special keys comes through to the Main form. Or I might be missing something..

Comment: @TotteKarlsson: Yes, because you are trying to catch the keys in the Form window, but the button window has the input focus, so the key messages go to the button instead. I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I got the code working with your suggestions above. Great, and great story about the Key in suggested link.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing this a bit differently (no **WinAPI** needed). If your **VCL** app has no focus on any sub component (like `TButton,TEdit,TMemo`...) then Main form keyboard events (`OnKeyDown` and `OnKeyUp`) will fire on arrow keys use. There are 2 approaches for this I know of:

1. **do not use components with focus**

   it may sound silly but you can have `TSpeedButton` instead of `TButton`. but essentially you can place all focusable components in some sub-window or page and make it invisible if not needed (like setup window).
2. **disable focus when arrows are needed**

   Simply I make an `unfocus` function like this:

   ```
   void main_unfocus()
       {
       Main->bt_unfocus->Visible=true;
       Main->bt_unfocus->SetFocus();
       Main->bt_unfocus->Visible=false;
       }
   ```

   where `bt_unfocus` is invisible 2x2 `TButton` placed in top left corner of main window `Main`. Now whenever I need to capture events like mouse wheel, arrow keys etc in the main form events then I just call the `main_unfocus();`

   I usually call it on mouse click on some viewing area or mouse move over it etc and Also I call this on hitting escape on any such component like `TButton,TMemo,TEdit` as they usually share the same event handlers in my Apps. All depends on what functionality you need/want.

**PS** hope you set the `KeyPreview` property to `true`.

Comment: I guess I could take your 1st approach, as I only have 4 buttons on a form. However, in case thats not possible, then the WndProc approach may be the way??

Comment: @TotteKarlsson I am not that familiar with **WinAPI** as I do not use it too often but I guess it is a way. The second approach works without **WinAP**I too you do not need to override any `WndProc` you just add the 3 line function and single button to your project + call it time to time (when needed) that is it ....  I use it all the time for huge projects like **CAD/CAM** with a lot of components and subwindows without any problems ....

Comment: @TotteKarlsson Also hope you're using `OnKeyDown/Up` instead of `OnKeyPress` as that does not return extended key codes only **ASCII**....

Comment: I tried your approach #2, and indeed, it works fine.

Curious, I assume the function is giving focus to the main form, and therefore trapping the arrow keys works, but you call the function main_unfocus. What's the rationale for 'unfocus'?

Comment: @TotteKarlsson it unfocus any sub component ... leaving focus to parent window of `bt_unfocus` which is Main form in my case